# How does ‘piercing the corporate veil’ work for publicly traded companies?

Tags: finance

I have read a bit on the internet about personal and firm bankruptcy.

I know the bankruptcy process for companies on several business structures (such as LLC’s [limited liability companies] and joint-stock companies [like the ones whose stock is frequently traded in Wall Street]) is such that the “owners” have limited liability to the amount they have put in the company and not owe anything more, i.e. the company ceases operations and their investment/equity value on the company goes to $0$, distributing the company’s total assets among its creditors (claim priorities according to law).

But I know there is an exception to this rule called “piercing the corporate veil” in which creditors can pursue full payment for their debts from the owners’ personal assets (beyond what is in the company), so owners would lose their entre investment in the company plus more of their personal assets, i.e. their investment/equity value on the company becomes negative.

I just watched this video from YouTube channel Wall Street Millenial: https://youtu.be/nNOT5sRyiyE

The video is about the Johnson and Johnson’s (JnJ) cancer case which could potentially hit them with a 300 billion dollar liability. JnJ is reportedly cheating its victims through “Texas Two Step Bankruptcy” in which a company can split into two and distribute its assets and liabilities between the two and have the liability heavy sub-company declare for bankruptcy, to protect the rest of the original company’s assets hiding on the other sub-company.

By the way, the Texas Two Step Bankruptcy is explained on Investopedia, at this link:

https://www.investopedia.com/texas-two-step-bankruptcy-definition-5225888

Between 6:16 and 7:36 on video, the chairman mentions that JnJ should get their corporate veil pierced.

My question is: in this case, since JnJ is a publicly traded company, would innocent people who just happened to buy their stock be personally liable for the excess liability generated by the lawsuits (and have their ‘investment value’ become negative rather than just $0)?

Comment: this seems to be question about bankruptcy law not economics so I will move it to Law.SE

Comment: "Innocent people" are not at risk at all. At risk are people who hid their own illegal actions behind a corporation. You must personally do something wrong to be at any risk.

Comment: @gnasher729 so the “piercing the corporate veil” penalty would only apply to significant shareholders, who have active roles in the company?